# How to synchronise instance data on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I write a CRON job which fetches some external data and saves it on the GAE instance - will it become available across all instances?

I am using `nodejs flexible` env.

Answer (score 0):

While you do have access to the GAE instance disk, the data in an instance is not replicated trough the rest. This is why it is recommended that you write all information to a Cloud Storage bucket, this way you can use this repository in order to share the data across the instances.

Comment: Thank you, and to ensure all instances are synced - will a CRON job run on all instances or a single one?

Comment: App Engine Cron jobs do not run on the instances. These cron jobs are automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service, so this would not make your instances synced

Comment: A cron job makes an HTTP GET request to a URL as scheduled. The handler for that URL executes the logic when it is called. So why could the handler not download data from the cloud bucket?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to a CRON Job directly created on the Flexible instances not to [App Engine Cron Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml). So the answer is **no**, it won't be available to all instances. It will only be stored to the instance(s) that executed that cron job at that time, meaning that if you have autoscaling enabled, all the new instances will not contain the external data.